# How do you transfer a search variable to the url in the navigation bar on the action page with a form?

Tags: html

I saw this done earlier and would like to know how to do it.

With this search form:

```
<form action="/search" class="searchform" method="post">
```

Lets say you search "help", it would display the action page url as:

http://www.site.com/search/help

How is this done? Because when I do it on my site, the same form would just return:

http://www.site.com/search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look into URL rewrite](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/)

You didn't state your server side language so I can't help on the server side code.
But you need to [google vitrual folder](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=php%20url%20rewrite&oq=php%20url%20&aq=6&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=348l5805l0l12716l8l5l0l0l0l0l228l867l0.2.3l5#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=php%20virtual%20folder&pbx=1&oq=php%20virtual%20folder&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=10458l14825l7l15146l16l12l1l7l7l0l300l1119l2.3.1.1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=fb9a7a497d49df1a&biw=1378&bih=778) also.

Comment: duh! sorry I should have known I have no idea why it didn't cross my mind. sorry for this lazy post